# reactDOM' is not defined no-undef

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I am getting an error in my index.js file:

`Failed to compile src\index.js`
`Line 5:1:  'reactDOM' is not defined  no-undef`

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.
This error occurred during the build time and cannot be dismissed.

My code in the index.js is:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const element = <h1>Hello, World!</h1>
reactDOM.render(element, document.getElementById("root"))
```

I am on a windows machine.

Please help me as quickly and accurately as possible, please.

Comment: And, please properly format the code and use snippet before pasting it

Answer (score 0):

It should be `ReactDOM`  not `reactDOM` (in the ReactDOM.render).